# Mockito: Mock a method call inside another method

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

So I'm trying to mock a method call inside another method, here's the pseudo code

```
class A{

    public String getAName(String id){
        B b = new B();
        // do something
        return b.getBName(id);
    }
}

testgetName{

    public void testA(){

        B mockB = mock(B.class);        
        Mockito.doReturn("Bar").when(mockB).getBName(id);

        A a = new A();
        a.getAName(id); //this still calls "b.getBName(id)" in class implementation
    }

}
```

The problem here is `a.getAName` still calls  `b.getBName(id)` - not sure why?

Any suggestions on how should I mock `b.getBName(id)` properly

Thanks

Comment: You cannot mock objects that are created by your object under test with `new`, since you have no control over those objects. You would have to make the `B` a field of class `A` and then inject it during your test. This is one of the reasons why people like dependency injection :)

Comment: One suggestion, you have a comment in your code that reads `// do something`. I will if this is a method call that takes B, to mock this method, or even better, use an ArugmentCaptor to capture the `B` passed to the method. This all hinges on what `// do something` actually does

Answer (score 7):

Because you are not injecting/using the mock object inside class A. In class A you are creating a new B object. So, mock object is never used. To fix this change your Class A implementation to below:

B as member of class:

```
class A{
  B b;

  public String getAName(String id){

    // do something
    return b.getBName(id);
  }
}
```

then in your test method inject the mock object to the B member inside class A. See below:

```
public void testA()(){
    B mockB = mock(B.class);
    Mockito.doReturn("Bar").when(mockB).getBName(id);
    A a = new A();
    a.b = mockB; //add this line to use mock in A
    String testStr = a.getAName(id); //this still calls "b.getBName(id)" in class implementation
    System.out.println(testStr);

}
```